# url_for not working inside jinja2 template, giving "not Defined" error

Tags: templates, flask, jinja2

I am new to Flask and trying to create a layout template using Jinja2.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='bundle/login.styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
       <title>{{meta['title']}}</title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <div class="app" id="app">
          {% block content %}
          {% endblock %}
       </div>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='bundle/login.bundle.js') }}"></script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

The problem is I get error `jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError` when i use `template.render()`:

```
    jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'url_for' is undefined
```

It works fine when i use `render_template()` though. No error is generated. I dont know what i am doing wrong.

Also, what is the difference between using `Jinja2.Environment` and `jinga.get_template()` to generate template vs simply using `render_template()`

Answer (score 2):

I've just passed the function `url_for` to `render`. It worked!

```py
return make_response(current_app.safe_env.get_template('template.html').render(url_for=url_for))
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `render_template()` this will also take care of adding the `url_for()` function to global variables available in templates.

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/templating/#standard-context

If you do not have that done, then it will not be available.

If you want to look under the hood, a starting point for this particular question might be here:

https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/flask/templating.py#L121

https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/flask/app.py#L699

Comment: So is there any apparent reason i would want to define Jinja2.Environment and get_template instead of simply using render_template() in flask?

Comment: @dabishan If you wanted a customized Jinja environment, but you would probably rather override `create_jinja_environment()` in this case, unless it'd be a one-shot usage of said environment. Can't really think of a scenario for it, but that doesn't mean there isn't one.